# NASM local variables - are they, in fact, global macros?

Tags: macros, nasm

I've been using the `%local` directive in NASM to define local variables and thus avoid typing `[ebp - 8]`, `[ebp - 24]` etc. all the time.

However, I noticed that a `local` variable defined in one function between the preprocessor context `%push` and `%pop` is still available in the rest of the code, which may result in unexpected parsing errors.

Here, I've written a minimal example demonstrating the problem:

```
    struc Rect
            .left           resd    1
            .top            resd    1
            .width          resd    1
            .height         resd    1
    endstruc

    %define RECT(x)  g_rect + Rect. %+ x


    segment .bss
    g_rect      resd        4

    segment .text

    ; ================================================
    function1:
            %push
            %stacksize flat
            %assign %$localsize 0
            %local width:dword        ; defines local var "width"
            push ebp
            mov ebp, esp
            sub esp, 4
            pusha

            ; ...

            popa
            leave
            ret
            %pop

    ; ================================================
    function2:
            push ebp
            mov ebp, esp
            pusha

            ; ...
            mov eax, RECT(height)   ; OK
            mov ebx, RECT(width)    ; Parse error
            ; ...

            popa
            leave
            ret
```

The exact error is:

```
nasm -f elf -d ELF_TYPE -g test.asm
test.asm:42: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
```

Obviously, it happens because `width` is getting substituted with something else, and if I remove the local param definition, the problem goes away.

As you can see, the variable `width` is still available after the `%pop`. This doesn't look very local to me! I'd expect NASM to undefine `width` when the `%pop` is executed.

Is there a way to use `%local` but avoid these leaking macros? At the moment they act as a simple `%define` statement which is confusing.

Comment: Post the error you are getting.

Comment: @FrankC. done. Don't think the exact error is relevant though

Comment: You have found a defect. The simplest work-around is to use unique names for %local that don't conflict with global ones, Others include (in ugliest order)  Create field by field direct reference macros (i.e. `%define RECTW g_rect+Rect.width` Stop using your RECT macro...